# Trying to access another MovieClip on frame 2 of a movieclip on main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working with nesting of movieclips.

I am trying to access another movieclip in frame 2 of main movieclip on stage.

=> test2 movieclip is present on frame2 of test movieclip.

I am getting this error because of accessing test2 variable..

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/Access()  at
>   Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/Untitled_fla::frame1()

Any alternate method to access test2 movieclip on frame2 of main movieclip?

My Code is :

```
var test1:MovieClip;
var test2:MovieClip;
test.stop();

function Start(){
    //test.addChild(test1);
    //Test1 = new test1();
    //Test2 = new test2();
    trace(test.numChildren);
    test1 = MovieClip(test.getChildByName("test1"));
    test.gotoAndStop(2);
    test2 = MovieClip(test.getChildByName("test2"));

}
function Access(color:String){
    var r:RegExp=new RegExp(/#/);
    var uintColor:uint = uint(String(color).replace(r,"0x"));
    var c: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    c.alphaMultiplier = 0.9;
    c.color = uintColor;
    test.gotoAndPlay(2);
    test2.transform.colorTransform = c;
}
Start();
Access("#666666");
```

Comment: right now you're just informing us that you do that. what is your question? what are your issues? what is happening and what *should* happen?

Comment: > I am getting this error...

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/Access()
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/Untitled_fla::frame1()

Comment: it means one of your variables is `null`. Most probably it's the `test` or `test2` variable. you must assign a value to a variable before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flash while moving though he timeline flash player creates the nested children only in the end of frame (except the first frame) that is, if you have child named `test2` in he second frame of `clip` and navigate to this frame you have to wait 1 frame before the children in this 2nd frame will be creared. Try the following solution:

```
function Start(){
    trace(test.numChildren);
    test1 = MovieClip(test.getChildByName("test1"));
    test.gotoAndStop(2);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(event:Event):void
    {
        EventDispatcher(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
        test2 = MovieClip(test.getChildByName("test2"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Access function. I think test2 wont be available if you are playing **test** MovieClip.

```
function Access(color:String){
    var r:RegExp=new RegExp(/#/);
    var uintColor:uint = uint(String(color).replace(r,"0x"));
    var c: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    c.alphaMultiplier = 0.9;
    c.color = uintColor;
    test.gotoAndStop(2);
    test2.transform.colorTransform = c;
}
```